# How to draw multiple filled confidence bands on one plot using R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have tried the following code to draw two filled bands on one plot, but `plotly` is not filling between the right pair of lines.  What is the correct way to do this?

I would also appreciate knowing how to specify the ideal transparency for handling overlap of two bands.

```
require(plotly)
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
g <- c('a','a','b','b')
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
lo <- y - .1
hi <- y + .1

a <- plot_ly(x=x, y=y, group=g)
a <- add_trace(a, x=x, y=lo, group=g, fill='tonexty')
a <- add_trace(a, x=x, y=hi, group=g)
a
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you want your plot to look like but you can try creating the plot in `ggplot2` using the `geom_ribbon` function. Then use `ggplotly` to convert the plot to a `plotly` graph:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x, g, y, lo, hi
)

plot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=g)) + geom_line(aes(x=x)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lo,ymax=hi), alpha=0.25) 

ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: That is the approach I have been using; I'm just finding inside one of my R packages that putting multiple `plotly` plots together is resulting in part of the image being lost and I wanted to better control the output using `plotly` directly.

Answer (score 1):

`fill = "tonexty"` fills according to what trace came before it.  So, one way to make it fill from the hi to lo for each group is to order the calls explicitly:

```
a <- plot_ly(x=x, y=y, group=g)
a <- add_trace(a, x = x[g=="a"], y = lo[g=="a"], group = g[g=="a"])
a <- add_trace(a, x = x[g=="a"], y = hi[g=="a"], group = g[g=="a"], fill = 'tonexty')
a <- add_trace(a, x = x[g=="b"], y = lo[g=="b"], group = g[g=="b"])
a <- add_trace(a, x = x[g=="b"], y = hi[g=="b"], group = g[g=="b"], fill = 'tonexty')
```

One way to specify the transparency is using `toRGB`

```
a <- plot_ly(x=x, y=y, group=g)
a <- add_trace(a, x = x[g=="a"], y = lo[g=="a"], group = g[g=="a"])
a <- add_trace(a, x = x[g=="a"], y = hi[g=="a"], group = g[g=="a"], fill = 'tonexty',
         fillcolor = toRGB("red", 0.1))
a <- add_trace(a, x = x[g=="b"], y = lo[g=="b"], group = g[g=="b"])
a <- add_trace(a, x = x[g=="b"], y = hi[g=="b"], group = g[g=="b"], fill = 'tonexty',
         fillcolor = toRGB("blue", 0.7))
a
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the tonexy misunderstanding.  Is there a way to let group= or color= do the work of automatically separating into the 2 groups?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Hm, I'm not sure that there is.  Maybe there is a way using `lapply`, but I'll have to think about it.

Comment: The implication is that `add_trace` is not "group aware" when starting a new polygon, right?

Comment: @FrankHarrell That seems to be the case.

Comment: @FrankHarrell FWIW, this will allow you not to specify each group explicitly, but it is obviously inefficient and not ideal.  Not sure if it's useful to you or not:  `a <- lapply(unique(g), function(ii) {  a <<- add_trace(a, x = x[g==ii], y = lo[g==ii], group = g[g==ii]);  a <<- add_trace(a, x = x[g==ii], y = hi[g==ii], group = g[g==ii], fill = 'tonexty')
});  a[[length(a)]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
g <- c('a','a','b','b')
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
lo <- y - .1
hi <- y + .1
df <- cbind.data.frame(x,y,g,lo,hi)
g.uni <- unique(df$g)

fig <- df %>%
        plot_ly(type = "scatter",
        mode = "lines",
        showlegend = FALSE)

for(i in g.uni){
      fig <- fig  %>%
               add_fun(function(plot) {
                  plot %>% 
                  filter(g == i) %>%
                  add_ribbons(x = ~x,
                      ymin = ~lo,
                      ymax = ~hi
                  ) %>%
                  add_lines(
                   x = ~x,
                   y = ~y,
                   line = list(
                            color = "black",
                            dash = "dot"
                            )
                         )
                  }
               )
}
print(fig)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLp22.jpg)